# Gradle: passing parameters to `apply from: <file>`

Tags: android, gradle

I'd like to put some common boilerplate `gradle` script code into shared `.gradle` file. Then, I can reuse it using `apply from:` statement.

The question is whether it's possible to pass parameters to applied script?
For example, I'd like to reuse the following boiler plate:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'

configurations {
    apt
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is here: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`. I'd like to reuse this code either for application projects or android library projects. So I need some parameter in order to decide which plugin to apply:

```
// assuming <isApplicationProject> - is a script parameter
if (isApplicationProject) {
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
} else {
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
}
```

Of course, I can just define some project-level property in this particular case, but I'd like to know whether it's possible to pass parameters upon script invocation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. apply from: is line include<> you cannot pass parameters.
2. however it does run on the same context and therefor on the same project, so you can do something of:`ext.isUsingApp=true; apply from: 'xxx'`
3. if that's the only difference i would advise you to do something of the following:

   myinclude.gradle:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
   apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'

   configurations {
       apt
   }

   android {
       compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
       buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

       defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
           targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
           versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
           versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled true
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }
   ```

then in your build.gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../includes/myinclude.gradle'
```

then in your libs build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: '../includes/myinclude.gradle'
```

for a simple Boolean no need to create parameter.